# bcrypt is not checking case sensitivity of the password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt, password-hash

I am using ExpressJS and MongoDB. I am using bcrypt for hashing the password before storing it in the database.
Here is the code :

`if (bcrypt.compare(req.body.password === result.password))`

How can I make it case sensitive? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, bcrypt.compare IS case sensitive

Comment: why do you use compare if you want to store the password into the database? compare is usually used if somebody wants to login then you need to compare his plaintext with the stored hash in the database

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are using the `bcrypt.compare` function incorrectly.

From the docs found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
bcrypt.compare(someOtherPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == false
});
```

And here's a complete, working example with an upper vs. lower case password checked:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const testPassword = '12345678abcdefg';

// generate a hash:
bcrypt.hash(testPassword, 10, function(err, hash) {
    // test a wrong password:
    const nonMatchingPassword = '12345678ABCDEFG';
    bcrypt.compare(nonMatchingPassword, hash, function(err, matches) {
        console.log('should not match:', matches);
        // test the right password:
        bcrypt.compare(testPassword, hash, function(err, matches) {
            console.log('should match:', matches);
        });
    });
});
```

The output from this example:

```
should not match: false
should match: true
```